# Node js + override the session value

Tags: node.js, session

I tried the following code to override the session value.

```
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var sess;
```

step:1

```
router.post("/login", function(req, res) {
    var email = "aaa@gmail.com";
    sess = req.session;
    sess.email = email;
    res.send({
        data : sess
    });
});
```

step:2

```
router.post("/update", function(req, res) {
    var email = "bbb@gmail.com";
    sess = req.session;
    sess.email = reqData.email;
    res.send({
        data : sess
    });
});
```

step:3

```
router.get("/check", function(req, res) {
    sess = req.session;
    var email = sess.email;
    console.log(email);
    //Here display first value.(aaa@gmail.com)
    //how can i get email value (bbb@gmail.com)?
});
```

How can I override the session value?

In third step need to get stet-2 value(bbb@gmail.com) but there I am getting aaa@gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

you just use session features , then try it

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: false, saveUninitialized: true,cookie: { path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: 30 * 30000 },rolling: true}));
```

I think this help to you